# How to get Kerberos credential from domain controller

Tags: c++, windows, iis, kerberos

My computer has joined a windows domain, but I logged in my computer as a local account, not a domain account. And I failed to get Kerberos credential by calling AcquireCredentialsHandle(). Is it possible to get Kerberos credential for local account? Just like IIS, it runs with "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" account, this account is also a local account. How does IIS get Kerberos credential from domain controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement ist not true. Microsoft's [reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998749%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) says in chapter "Exchange Services and the LocalSystem Account
"

> This account does not have a password.
>   The NetworkService account corresponds to the computer account of the local computer in the domain. An Exchange service that runs in the security context of the LocalSystem account uses the local computer account credentials when accessing domain resources, such as Active Directory, over the network.

Log on with a domain account or use [`LogonUserEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've solved my problem by running my program with LocalSystem account. I also tried to run with NetworkService account, but failed due to insufficient privilege. I didn't know that NetworkService account uses the computer account of the local computer.