# IIS: Using Kerberos with client computers that are not on the domain

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, iis, active-directory, kerberos

Can a computer that is NOT a part of the domain (but is on the network) authenticate against to a web site published by IIS8 where the authentication for that site is "Windows Authentication" only with a single provider of "Negotiate:Kerberos" (and with Kernel-mode authentication disabled)?

I ask because I am trying to do just this, but I cannot get past the authentication to the site (yet alone trying to pass the authentication to the database). I see the "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate" header on the response to the client, but the client only ever seems to send a "NTLM Type1: Negotiation" (NTLMSSP) in the subsequent (re)requests. Either that or I am interpreting the results from Fiddler2 incorrectly!

I am using Kerberos as most of the clients will be domain computers and I need to pass user credentials from the web application back to the database. I was hoping that I would be able to do the same with non-domain computers and they would simply be prompted for a username/domain/password that would be validated and converted to a Kerberos ticket on the server.

Note that for testing purposes, Windows 8 is both the server and the client. In production, the server will be Windows 2008 Server R2 and the client will be primarily Windows 7 (though there will be some Windows 8 clients).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kerberos will **not** work on accounts/computers which are not part of the domain.
You have two options to achive your goal:

1. Request the user data with Basic auth and pass that to `LogonUserEx`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203228/696632) for answers.
2. Authenticate the user by other means and use [S4U2self](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13818954/696632) (protocol transition).

Comment: I had a horrible feeling that was going to be the case. I guess that, for now, the application will only be available to computers that are part of the domain. I had hoped that it could be available to any domain user on any computer that was simply on the LAN but I need to be able to use automatic Windows Authentication for the local users whilst passing the credentials from the IIS server to the SQL server.

Comment: @MartinRobins, what did you expect? If someone isn't part of the domain he/she cannot obviously use Kerberos. There is not hidden magic.

Comment: I was expecting a similar experience to NTLM; if the computer is not on the domain, pop up a log on dialog and then authenticate the credentials provided against the domain. Then use those credentials in any double hop. I now understand that with Kerberos the browser is actually responsible for getting these credentials from the domain in the first place and sending them with the request - hence the reason that it cannot work from a computer that is not on the domain.#

Comment: This is really old, but assuming your KDC is accessible over the internet,  why can't the client just 'kinit user@DOMAIN' and get a ticket useable for authentication?

I've had plenty of *nix machines on which a user could kinit and get a kerberos ticket, use the ticket to access remote servers, but the nix machines themselves were not part of the domain.

Comment: @CVVS, just because the machine did not join the domain, it does not mean that a user cannot `kinit` into a domain. This is decoupled. And yes, if your KDC is available over the net and all DNS entries are fine, that should be fine too.